# Calculating the first order partial derivatives of $z(x,y.)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

My function is $z^3 - 3xyz = 1$ and I calculated $z_{x}^{'}$ and I got $z_{x}^{'} = \frac{yz + yy^{'}z}{z^{2} - xy }$. but the answer at the back of the book is  $z_{x}^{'} = \frac{yz}{z^{2} - xy },$ could anyone clarify for me if I am wrong and why?

Comment: Your answer is correct but $y'=0$; so ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get by the chain rule $$3z^2z_x-3yz-3xyz_x=0$$ so $$z_x(z^2-xy)=yz$$
Hint: By the quotient rule we obtain
$$z_{xx}=\frac{yz_x(z^2-xy)-yz(2zz_x)}{(z^2-xy)^2}$$ and for $$z_x$$ you must plug in $$z_x=\frac{yz}{z^2-xy}$$

Comment: what about finding the second order partial derivatives ..... how can I think about it?

Comment: You want to calculate $$z_{xx}(x,y)$$?

Comment: yes please I want this.